# Entity framework, can I map a class to a key/value table?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, database-design

In my Database, I have a key/value table, which I use to store the configuration of the application. Some example settings of the StoreConfiguration class, that I want to map to this key/value table.

```
 public class StoreConfiguration
 {

    //.... more settings

    public int DefaultPartnerID { get; set; }

    public int DefaultOperatorID { get; set; }

    public string DefaultCurrency { get; set; }

    public int DefaultCurrencyID { get; set; }

    //.... more settings
```

I would like to have those in my DataBase as this for example

```
Key               | Value
--------------------------
DefaultpartnerID  | 1
DefaultOperatorID | 10
DefaultCurrency   | USD
DefaultCurrencyID | 2
```

Is it possible to create such type of mapping with EntityFramework ?

Comment: That would be uncommon, what if there are two objects of `StoreConfiguration`, which value that will be added to the `Value` column, first object / second object? Or you want to add both keys (which means that will be multiple `Key`? If that so, which one is the PK? You might want just have a normal entity which has `Key` column and `Value` column.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to use a simple entity that contains `Key` and `Value` property.

```
public class StoreConfiguration
{
    [Key]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then provide an extension to add and remove the store configuration.

```
public static class StoreConfigurationExtension
{
    public static T GetStoreConfiguration<T>(this DbContext db, string key)
    {
        var sc = db.Set<StoreConfiguration>().Find(key);
        if (sc == null) return default(T);

        var value = sc.Value;
        var tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
        try
        {
            var convertedValue = (T)tc.ConvertFromString(value);
            return convertedValue;
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public static void SetStoreConfiguration(this DbContext db, string key, object value)
    {
        var sc = db.Set<StoreConfiguration>().Find(key);
        if (sc == null)
        {
            sc = new StoreConfiguration { Key = key };
            db.Set<StoreConfiguration>().Add(sc);
        }

        sc.Value = value == null ? null : value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage.

```
using (var db = new AppContext())
{
    db.SetStoreConfiguration("DefaultpartnerID", 1);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
using (var db = new AppContext())
{
    var defaultpartnerID = db.GetStoreConfiguration<int>("DefaultpartnerID");
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, entity framework is not meant for this. But you still can use reflection to load data into this class.

```
var entities = ...;
var o = new StoreConfiguration();
foreach(var p in typeof(StoreConfiguration).GetProperties())
{
   var entity = entities.FirstOrDefault(e=>e.Key == p.Name);
   if (entity == null) continue;

   var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConvertor(p.Type);
   p.SetValue(o, converter.ConvertFromString(entity.Value));
}
```

Comment: I thought about this too at first, but how about if there are 2 objects of `StoreConfiguration`, which one that will be updated to the database? the last got executed?

Comment: You can add id column to key value table and filter by it